# How to solve bi-directional road network using Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, network-flow

I have been given problem of a road network as shown in picture. It shows a network of one-way streets with traffic flowing in the directions indicated. The flow rates along the streets are measured as the average number of vehicles per hour.

[Given Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja4St.png)

There are two questions asked which I am trying to solve :-

```
1. Is it possible to close the road from A to B for construction and
    keep traffic flowing on other streets? Justify your answer.

 2. Suppose all the streets (from A to B, B to C etc.) are
    bidirectional, leaving the other constants as it is along with the
    direction, how to formulate the system of equations.
```

I have found the unknown flow rates and are coming as below :-

```
x1 = 50 + x6, x2 = 450 +x7, x3 = 750 - x6, x4 = 600 -x6 +x7, x5 = -50 +x7
where x6 and x7 are free variables.
```

How can I solve above two questions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.

Comment: Sure @saulspatz

Comment: It seems this question depends on some domain-specific terms and definitions. For instance what does it mean to "keep traffic flowing"? Where are the equations in the second section coming from?

Comment: @user7530 Its related to road network. Equation in second section are coming after I tried to find the unknown x1, x2.

Comment: In your original computation of the flows, you haven’t taken into account the constraint that they are unidirectional. You will need to use this constraint to answer question 1.

Comment: @amd I have found the variables x1, x2 using the unidirectional approach and need to know how will I use this constraint to answer question 1?

Comment: How does unidirectionality affect the ranges of acceptable values for the flows?